# Bacula: Upgrade from Incremental to Full issue?

Tags: backup

Using Bacula 5.2.6 I have:

```
Job1 :
    Client1
    Storage1
    Schedule1 (Tue at 21:00)
    Pool1 (Volume1)
    Fileset1
    Full
```

And

```
Job2 :
    Client1
    Storage1
    Schedule2 (Wed at 22:00)
    Pool2 (Volume2)
    Fileset1
    Incremental
```

I run Job1 manually successfully on Volume1 (Full).
But when running Job2 I got:

```
No prior or suitable Full backup found in catalog. Doing FULL backup.
Backup Level: Full (upgraded from Incremental)
```

I think Job1's already done Fileset1 Full backup on Volume1, why doesn't Job2 perform a Fileset1 Incremental backup on Volume2 without upgrading to Full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

The incremental backup is based on the full backup executed with:

- The same Job name. (in my case I have different jobs: Job1 and Job2)
- The same Client name.
- The same FileSet (any change to the definition of the FileSet such as adding or deleting a file in the Include or Exclude sections constitutes a different FileSet.

Why isn't it based only on the same Client and the same Fileset only?